# SQL query to count of two columns in one

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb-10.3

| s.fruit | fruit |
| --- | --- |
| Cucumber | apple |
| apple | Mango |
| Orange | grape |
| grape | apple |

My output need to be the count be of the total fruit.

```
apple:3,
Mango :1,
grape:2,
Cucumber:1, 
orange:1.
```

This is what i tried which is not correct
so how to do this ? any idea?

```
select s.fruit,fruit, count(*) 
from grocery
group by s.fruit,fruit
```

Comment: Using dots in your column names is bad practice as it collides with table qualifier syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
select fru,count(*) from (
select `s.fruit` as fru
  from grocery
union all
select fruit as fru
  from grocery
)x
group by fru
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd try something like this:

```
SELECT fr, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM (
  SELECT `s.fruit` AS fr FROM grocery
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT fruit AS fr FROM grocery
) t
GROUP BY fr
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use sub-query and combine with 'union all' in the solution.